# How to work with session + javascript + updatepanel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session, updatepanel

I am storing some values in session on button click event. I am also calling javascript from code behind. I want to access the session values in javascript but i am unable to since i am using updatepanel. Kindly post appropriate answer !!

Comment: check this link http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/04/Get-Session-value-in-JavaScript.html

Answer (score 0):

How about calling a javascript function from code behind and passing session values as function parameters.

e.g code behind

```
private sub RunJScript()
  ScriptManage.registerStartupScript(Page,gettype(page),"myMeth","myMeth('"& val1 &"')")
end sub
```

client side

```
<script>
   function myMeth(vl){
       //do what you want to do with javascript
       alert(vl);
      }
</script>
```

Comment: I am able to call function but i do not get the session values in javascript function which i save from code behind due to update panel.

Comment: i had the same problems with the update panel when my javascript was hooked to controls within the update panel so i had to use the "on" handler to make it work. So for example: "$('#<%=btn.ClientID%'>).on('click',function(){//do something});" So is your button within the update panel. If so the you need to use this type of javascript otherwise look for Page endrequestHandler and drop your javascript in there. But for some reason that some how did not work for me.